# "React without Node/npm" - Geting error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am set up a project in reactjs. The main thing important to be noted that I am not using node or npm to set up the project. It means, I directly use all scripting library files after downloading them and added them in my project. But, I am getting error of "exports is not defined".

[image]

One more thing to be noted that I cannot use import keyword in my project.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learn Reactjs</title>
        <script src="react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="DropDown.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var DropDown = require('DropDown');

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {this.props.message}!</h1>
            <DropDown />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage message="World" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**DropDown.js**

```
'use strict';

    var DropDown = React.createClass({
      render: function () {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>i am DropDown</h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    export default DropDown;
```

Comment: Why can you use `export` but not `import`?

Comment: please use `create-react-app` npm package for build react application

Comment: i found that 'import' will not work in my project structure because I am not using node /npm. I know that import will only work if I use node/npm to set up my project. So, I use export and require. If there is any solution from your side, please tell me that if it is applicable to use import and it will definitely work in my project structure but it should be noted that I am not using node/npm

Comment: You are missing the Babel bits. See https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation .

Comment: Essentially you need `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @uzaif: I cannot use node/npm. It is totally restricted for my project.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen: When I add <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></sc‌​ript>. I found an error : "require is not defined"

Comment: It probably does not implement CommonJS modules then, perhaps ES6 style only.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen:  Sorry, I did not understand your last comment. Please, can you explain it. really what I need to do?

Comment: Use ES6 import instead. So `import React from 'react'` as per specification.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen: I use "import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DropDown from './DropDown.js';" As per your saying. But, I still got error of exports in not defined .

Comment: You should check Babel docs for more info. Ideally you would have node/npm setup as otherwise you'll keep on tripping.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem.

**Step 1:** keep **index.html** as same as above.

**Step 2:** replace **index.js** file as per below code:

```
'use strict';


var DropDown = window.DropDown;

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {this.props.message}!</h1>
            <DropDown />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage message="World" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Step 3:** replace **DropDown.js** file with the below code:

```
'use strict';


window.DropDown = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>i am DropDown</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```